# Flask socket.io gunicorn chat app stuck in redirect loop

Tags: flask, https, socket.io, gunicorn

I have a basic flask socket.io chat app that's built the same as this example https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat

I can run the app with `gunicorn mychat:app --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --reload` and then `autossh -M 0 -R myappname:80:localhost:5000 serveo.net` and hitting the appropriate serveo.net url.

I'm trying to deploy this on an AWS EC2 instance behind a loadbalancer with HTTPS. On the EC2 instance I installed nginx as here: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-nginx-as-a-websocket-reverse-proxy (the single example, not the multiple nodes example).

When I go to the URL I defined from my loadbalancer target group, and i enter a chatroom, I see that in the Network tab of my browser, there are tons of rapid polling requests that keep giving a 200 then a 301. If I join the chatroom in another tab, the users are not able to send message to each other.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around, I figured it out. My host, example.com, points to a load balancer with a bunch of listener rules. I made it so that if path=/mychatapp/*, then forward to the ec2 instance running the app. This is fine, but socket.io was making calls with host=example.com so it was hitting example.com/socket.io/etcetcetc... I added another load balancer listener rule if path=/socket.io/*, then also forward it to the ec2 instance. This works out.

This solution is pretty hacky since it means I couldn't run a second socket.io app. A better answer would be to somehow change the default call from "/socket.io" to "/mychatapp/socket.io" so that I wouldn't require another listener rule. I tried a few ways to do this, but it didn't work. Since this is a small project, I will stick with this solution.